# Python Regular Expressions and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have CSV file I imported with Pandas.

I have some problem in CSV file:

1- First I need split string and float like(2_hour_serum_insulin0.0000) I need split to columns like (2_hour_serum_insulin) and (0.0000)

2- I need convert rows to columns

the first image see the garbage CSV, the second what i need.

[Garbage CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emesa.png)

[Perfect CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpRu0.png)

Thank you..

I try split in but I facing problems with string contain special character (_) and floating number.
Also I can't groups the rows to convert to columns.

Comment: What is the actual separator in the CSV file? You should specify that in the `delimiter=` option for `pd.read_csv()`.

Comment: Showing a few lines of the _"CSV file"_ and the code you use to _"[import] with Pandas"_ would be helpful.

Comment: The problem no delimiter like this (no_pregnant30.000) I need seprate to (no_pregnamt) and (30.000) how I can do that.

Comment: Hi Sadiq! Welcome to StackOverflow. If you could read this and update your question, that would be great! Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

[`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the two parts, [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) the time as new column, and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
out = (df['codes']
 .str.extract('(?P<col>.*?)(?P<value>\d+\.?\d*)?$')
 .astype({'value': float})
 .assign(times_pregnant=lambda d: d['value'].where(d['col'].eq('times_pregnant')).ffill())
 .pivot_table(index='times_pregnant', columns='col', values='value', aggfunc='mean')
)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L92nel/1)

Output:

```
col             2_hour_serum_insulin   BMI   age  diabetes  \
times_pregnant                                               
0.0                            168.0  43.1  33.0       1.0   
6.0                              0.0  33.6  50.0       1.0   
8.0                              0.0  23.3  32.0       1.0   

col             diabetes_pedigreen  diastolic_blood_pressure  \
times_pregnant                                                 
0.0                          2.288                      40.0   
6.0                          0.627                      72.0   
8.0                          0.672                      64.0   

col             plasma_glucose_concentration  times_pregnant  \
times_pregnant                                                 
0.0                                    137.0             0.0   
6.0                                    148.0             6.0   
8.0                                    183.0             8.0   

col             triceps_thickness  
times_pregnant                     
0.0                          35.0  
6.0                          35.0  
8.0                           0.0
```

Comment: your python-fu continues to amaze me

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "codes": [
        "times_pregnant6.0000",
        "plasma_glucose",
        "concentration148.0000",
        "diastolic_blood_pressure72.0000",
        "triceps_thickness35.0000",
        "2_hour_serum_insulin0.0000",
        "BMI33.6000",
        "diabetes_pedigreen0.6270",
        "age50.0000",
        "diabetes1.0000",
        "times_pregnant6.0000",
        "times_pregnant8.0000",
        "plasma_glucose_concentration183.0000",
        "diastolic",
        "blood",
        "_pressure64.0000",
        "triceps_thickness0.0000",
        "2_hour_serum_insulin0.0000",
        "BMI23.3000",
        "diabetes_pedigreen0.6720",
        "age32.0000",
        "diabetes1.0000",
        "times_pregnant8.0000",
        "times_pregnant0.0000",
        "plasma_glucose_concentration137.0000",
        "diastolic_blood_pressure40.0000",
        "triceps_thickness35.0000",
        "2_hour_serum_insulin168.0000",
        "BMI43.1000",
        "diabetes_pedigreen2.2880",
        "age33.0000",
        "diabetes1.0000"
    ]
})

df["value"] = df["codes"].str.extract(r"(\d+\.\d+)").astype(float)
df["codes"] = df["codes"].str.replace(r"\d+\.\d+", "")

                           codes    value
0                 times_pregnant    6.000
1                 plasma_glucose      NaN
2                  concentration  148.000
3       diastolic_blood_pressure   72.000
4              triceps_thickness   35.000
5           2_hour_serum_insulin    0.000
6                            BMI   33.600
7             diabetes_pedigreen    0.627
8                            age   50.000
9                       diabetes    1.000
10                times_pregnant    6.000
11                times_pregnant    8.000
12  plasma_glucose_concentration  183.000
13                     diastolic      NaN
14                         blood      NaN
15                     _pressure   64.000
16             triceps_thickness    0.000
17          2_hour_serum_insulin    0.000
18                           BMI   23.300
19            diabetes_pedigreen    0.672
20                           age   32.000
21                      diabetes    1.000
22                times_pregnant    8.000
23                times_pregnant    0.000
24  plasma_glucose_concentration  137.000
25      diastolic_blood_pressure   40.000
26             triceps_thickness   35.000
27          2_hour_serum_insulin  168.000
28                           BMI   43.100
29            diabetes_pedigreen    2.288
30                           age   33.000
31                      diabetes    1.000
```

This is as far as I can get to what you want based on the (screenshots) of data you have provided. As you can see from the table above, it's impossible to group the columns when times_pregnant appears in two consecutive columns.

Comment: No need for two commands, you can directly extract the two parts and overwrite the first column

Comment: @mozway I was playing around with positive lookaheads but couldn't seem to get it working 

Comment: I provided an example ;)